# "this" in a function in an object in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting very confused by the behavior of `this` in my node module.  Here is the relevant snippet:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var config = require('./config');

   return {
        config: config,
        agencies:  ["string1", "string2"],

        getRoutes: function(callback) {
            var API = "/api/route/";
            this.agencies.forEach( function(agency) {
                console.log(this.config); //Returns undefined??
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Looking at the [MDN documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) says that a `this` in a function in an object refers to the object.  I would then expect the `console.log(this.config)` to reference the require'd config module.  Instead, it's not clear what the `this` ends up referring to, other than that it doesn't have a "config" property.

Clearly there's a scope change going on somewhere, but I'm not sure where.  The forEach?  I tried to just `console.log(this)`, but I got back a huge object that I couldn't decipher.

**I don't understand why config is out of the scope of this function.  What's going on?**

Comment: Inside the `forEach` function, you are now in a different context.  So, `this` is different.

Comment: **Every** function call establishes a value for `this` inside the called function, including the call made to each iteration of your `.forEach` handler.

Comment: Note: some iterator functions (e.g. [`jQuery.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)) will establish a custom `this` context, such as the item being iterated. However, it's still a *different* function execution context.

Comment: A little off topic, but you don't need a reference to the returned object at all. You already have a `config` variable, which  `getRoutes` and the callback function will close over, so you can just do `console.log(config);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's `undefined` because the default value of `this` in a function is the global object.

To fix it, pass the object as the second argument to `.forEach()`

```
this.agencies.forEach( function(agency) {
    console.log(this.config)
}, this)
//   ^---sets the `this` value
```

---

The way `this` works is that it is determined by *how* the function is called. Because `.forEach()` doesn't know what you want for the `this` value in the callback, it leaves it at the default value, which is the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode.

By passing the second argument, you're telling it to manually set `this` to whatever you  provided.

How it accomplishes this (or how you can do it anyway) is to call a function using the `.call()` or `.apply()` method of the function.

```
myFunction.call({foo:"bar"});
```

Now `myFunction` will be invoked with the `{foo:"bar"}` object set as its `this` value.

Comment: I owe you an upvote, but don't have the rep.  This is a great answer, having both a correction and an explanation.

Comment: @ABMagil: Not a problem. Glad it helped.

Comment: One request- can you clarify in your example code comment that "sets the 'this' value" is referring to setting the 'this' within the function scope (assuming I understand correctly)?  On first reading, I wasn't sure what you meant.

Comment: @ABMagil: Yes the value of `this` in the execution of the function. While people sometimes refer to it as "scope", and it's not completely unrelated, talking about the value of `this` is technically not the same as talking about variable scope. The value of `this` in a function is a dynamic value that can be set implicitly or explicitly in a variety of different ways, so there isn't always a simple predictable value. Its predictability comes from the developer written code, or from the documentation of the API you're using.

Answer (score 3):

context switching occurs in the loop, because inside I believe this to be the "agencies"

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
var config = require('./config');

return {
    config: config,
    agencies:  ["string1", "string2"],

    getRoutes: function(callback) {
        var API = "/api/route/";
        var self = this;
        this.agencies.forEach( function(agency) {
            console.log(self.config); //Returns undefined??
        }
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` within a function depends on the circumstances in which it is created and invoked. When you use `forEach`, you're passing it an anonymous function as the first argument, which has its own block scope that `this` refers to.

There are several ways to control the value of `this` in a function. You can create a local reference in the parent scope, which is accessible via closure:

```
    getRoutes: function(callback) {
        var API = "/api/route/";
        var me = this; // local reference to the current scope
        this.agencies.forEach( function(agency) {
            console.log(me.config); // accessed via closure
        });
   }
```

... you can `bind` the function:

```
    getRoutes: function(callback) {
        var API = "/api/route/";
        this.agencies.forEach( function(agency) {
            console.log(this.config);
        }.bind(this))
   }
```

... or you can pass the context as a second argument to `forEach` and let the engine bind the scope for you:

```
    getRoutes: function(callback) {
        var API = "/api/route/";
        var me = this;
        this.agencies.forEach( function(agency) {
            console.log(this.config); 
        }, this);
   }
```

**Documentation**

- `forEach` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
- `bind` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: *"The scope of this within a function refers to the function itself."* That's not correct. In JavaScript it rarely refers to the function itself. To make it refer to the function, you'd need to do something like `myFunction.call(myFunction);` or `myFunction.func = myFunction; myFunction.func();`, both of which would be very unusual

Comment: @cookiemonster Eh, it could be worded better.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `this` depends on how the function it is in is called.

Here is the function it is in:

```
function(agency) {
    console.log(this.config); //Returns undefined??
}
```

It is passed as an argument to `agencies.forEach`. `agencies` is an array, so we can look at [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value.

So `this` is `undefined`.

You could pass in a different value for `this` as per the above documentation.

```
this.agencies.forEach( 
        function(agency) {
            console.log(this.config); //Returns undefined??
        },
        this
);
```

---

In this case, you can just use a closure. `config` (from `var config = require('./config');`) will still be in scope. So just use `config` instead of `this.config`.